# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo - AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a complete beginner to android/Java development and I massively appreciate any pointers anyone is able to give me on the issue I'm having. Here is the MainActivity.java.

```
package com.example.harris.enterappman;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}






EditText enterName;
TextView usersName;
String str = enterName.getText().toString();
public void getName(View view){

    enterName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterName);
    usersName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloNameView);
    usersName.setText(str);

}

public void printUsersName(){



}

}
```

Everytime I try and run the program, it fails with the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity             ComponentInfo{com.example.harris.enterappman/com.example.harris.enterappman.Main    Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.harris.enterappman.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:48)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1064)
        at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
            at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

From others posts online I have come to the conclusion that the problem is related to abstract methods? I was unable to work out how my code was wrong.

Cheers,
Harris

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = enterName.getText().toString();
```

`enterName` is `null` at this point, as you are not setting it ever. You are welcome to declare `String str;` as a field, but you cannot initialize it until after you set a value on `enterName`.

You have code to initialize `enterName` in a somewhat strange `getName()` method, but you do not appear to be calling that ever.

Answer (score 0):

how possible you are setting your `str` using `enterName`, as `enterName` is not initialized and hence it is `null` causing  Null pointer exception

you must have to initilize `enterName` before using it, as you are doing initialization in your `getName()` method, and then use it to get its text

your code must be like this and you have to call this method from `onCreate()`

```
public void getName(View view){

    enterName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterName);
    usersName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloNameView);
    usersName.setText(enterName.getText().toString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialised entername properly

either use:

```
....
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    enterName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterName);
    usersName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloNameView);
    usersName.setText(str);
}  
...
```

or use it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getName();
}

public void getName(){
    enterName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterName);
    usersName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloNameView);
    usersName.setText(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `enterName.getText()` when enterName is null, which leads to NullPointerException.

Few things I suggest:

- If you want to own references to the layout components, call these in the onCreate method:

> ```
> enterName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterName);
> usersName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloNameView);
> ```

- Don't call methods in the class itself (except some constructors), call them in a method (I refer to the str variable).